# Jquery Toggle Code Not Working On Windows Server 2008

Tags: jquery, windows

Hi Have a perculiar situation.

I downloaded this Simply Jquery Toggle from:

http://demo.webstutorial.com/slideToggle/

this is working perfectly fine using my IE8 from the website. I downloaded the file and ran it from my local machine without any problems great works fine in IE8.

I then copy the file across to my Windows Server 2008 and access the page and the functionality suddenly stops!! It now only works if I use firefox. anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Correct Roko. EDIT I attempt to run the file locally from the server and it doesn't work. Why would it not work on windows server 2008?

Comment: not correct. Remember this WORKS with every othe browswer

Comment: °° I need a sleep. Anyway, Andrew, paste the code here and provide a demo at least.

Comment: here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/EdHKx/

Comment: Download this one and test it... http://jsbin.com/ohiqub/1/edit

Comment: Most likely it's related to security settings. Security settings are usually defaulted way higher on servers. don't test code locally. use a webserver.

Comment: its strange..this has not prevented my from doing hundreds of other jquery projects that are running off the same box!

Roko your solution still doesn't like running from IE connecting to the server..firefox still works ok

Comment: when you say locally, do you mean, running from the filesystem

Comment: yes running from my Desktop on my PC

Comment: to add: When I to run this off my server opening on my IE8 on my local machine the CSS + content is not shown.

it basically looks like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/EdHKx/1/

Comment: pretty much guarantee windows 2008 has nothing to do with it. Either the path to the file is wrong, or the webserver (IIS, Apache, etc) you are using isn't serving the js files correctly.

Comment: Heck there aren't even any includes.

Comment: Well your comments Kevin arn't really helpfil..If i got the path wrong then it wouldn't work with other browsers. if it wasnt servicing the js file then all my other hundreds of applications wouldnt work either.

Comment: What does the console say? ... It's obviously an IE issue, but until you provide the error logs you're on your own.

Comment: well well!! I just looked on the concole and i noticed the document stand was set to IE7 which is why it wasnt working. I changed the document standard to IE8 and now its working! Does anyone know how to force this? assuming this will work:  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyones responses to this. It turned out that the group policy at work force windows document standard to IE7. Because of this the CSS script was unknown. I had to include this in the head to force it to IE8

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8">
```